# Makefile keeps some intermediates in multiple target rule

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I use the following Makefile section:

```
.PHONY: all
all: _MyModule.so

_%.so: %.pb.cc %.pb.h
    python setup.py build

%.pb.cc %.pb.h: %.proto
    protoc --cpp_out=. $^  # Generate these two files together
```

I would expect `make` to create the `_MyModule.so` file and remove the intermediates `MyModule.pb.cc` and `MyModule.pb.h`. What happens in practice is that only one of the files is deleted(`.h` or `.cpp`). I also noticed that it depends on the order of their appearance in the `_%.so` dependencies list.

Could anyone explain this behavior?

How could I elegantly remove all the intermediates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How peculiar. I'll go out on a limb and say this looks like a bug in GNUMake. A pattern rule with multiple targets has special behavior, and it seems that this behavior doesn't dovetail correctly with the treatment of intermediate files (and `.INTERMEDIATE` doesn't help).

I wouldn't call this an elegant solution, but it works:

```
%.pb.cc: %.pb.h
    @:

%.pb.h: %.proto
    ...
```

**P.S.** Turns out this is a [known bug](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=32042).

Comment: @Albert, `:` is the unix command for "do nothing", and when a command in a Make rule is preceded by `@` it means "do it quietly".